# Why can I SSH into my local server, only after running the ping command?

Tags: networking

I have multiple machines on my side of the router, my LAN. I've confirmed that they're all on the same router, and all have the same subnet mask. **192.168.0.1** and **255.0.0.0**

When I try to SSH from my Mac into my Ubuntu server using the local IP address, **192.168.0.5**, it fails.

However, if I take the following steps:

1. SSH into the same server using the real world IP address, **151.X.X.X**,
2. Have the server ping my Mac's local address, **192.168.0.10**
3. Try SSHing again from my Mac using the Local IP address again...

...then SSH using the local IP address works.

My feeling is I missed something in the Mac's network setup. But am unable to find out what it is.

*I say Mac, because my Mac and PC are the two machines that get shutdown and restarted everyday, the Ubuntu server, 18.04, just keeps running. Yet the PC can always SSH in, while with the Mac I have to go through the weird process above*

One more thing I have done is tried the checked answer I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently), setting:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

But that did not solve my issue.

Comment: I don't know if it affects your problem, but the 192.168.x.x block in RFC1918 is only /16 -- the subnet mask should be 255.255.0.0 or narrower (/24 = 255.255.255.0 is common).

Comment: Have tried everything people have suggested, including the above. I even have given the ubuntu server a reserved IP address. It sill happens tho